# Django Password Reset - DoesNotExist exception

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

The password_reset page of my Django site is causing a `DoesNotExist` exception after an email address is entered and the button pressed.

The four URLs required for the password reset function are in (the main project) urls.py as:

```
(r'^password_reset/$', 'appname.views.cust_password_reset'),
(r'^password_reset/done/', 'appname.views.cust_password_reset_done'),
(r'^reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 'appname.views.cust_password_reset_confirm'),
(r'^reset/done/$', 'appname.views.cust_password_reset_complete')
```

The following is the code used for the associated views:

```
def cust_password_reset(request):
    return password_reset(request, post_reset_redirect='password_reset/done',template_name='registration/password_reset_done.html')

def cust_password_reset_done(request):
    return password_reset_done(request,  template_name='registration/password_reset_done.html')

def cust_password_reset_confirm(request, uidb36=None, token=None):
    return password_reset_confirm(request, uidb36=uidb36, token=token,
    template_name='registration/password_reset_confirm.html',
    post_reset_redirect='registration/reset/done/')

def cust_password_reset_complete(request):
    return password_reset_complete(request,
    template_name='registration/password_reset_complete.html')
```

The email address is correctly checked for validity, but the redirect to password_reset/done doesn't appear to happen.  The URL stays as password_reset, but causes a DoesNotExist exception with the value 'Site matching query does not exist'.

The URLs and templates seem to work properly and password_reset/done displays correctly when manually accessed.
The templates referenced are exact copies of the original Django templates, with just a header/ footer added. Password Resetting without using custom views/templates results in the same error.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error, "Site matching query does not exist" means that the `SITE_ID` in settings.py does not match up with an actual `Site` object in the database. Check the `id` attribute for your site, and make sure it's the same as `SITE_ID`.

Comment: The `SITE_ID` in settings.py is 1, and I'm not (purposely at least) changing this anywhere else. In the Settings section of the Request Information shown when the error occurs, the `SITE_ID` is also 1, but this seems to be coming directly from settings.py. Is it possible that something in the password_reset views could be changing the id automatically?

Comment: That error is pretty explicit; there's only one thing that will cause that. Check your database and make sure site_id is 1 there.

Comment: It looks like there wasn't a `Site` object in the database at all - when I added one, it was given `id` 1 and now the password reset works perfectly - Thanks for your help.